# Managing static data

Tags: java, database, dbunit

I'm looking for a Java (or Groovy) solution for managing static data i.e. data in infrequently changing tables such as a list of countries.

I would like to keep the list of countries in a text file and have the tables automatically updated when the server starts. I can't simply delete all the tables, then re-insert the data in the text files because this would violate key constraints.

DbUnit is a library which supports loading data into a DB from an XML file. It has a [refresh operation](https://dbunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/dbunit/trunk/src/java/org/dbunit/operation/RefreshOperation.java) which *almost* does what I need. This will insert any rows that are in the file but not in the DB, update any rows in the DB which are also in the file, but it doesn't delete any rows that are in the DB but not in the file.

Has anyone found a good solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: If the data changes infrequently, why do you want to blat the whole table each time the server starts?  Would it not make more sense to have some database scripts which populate these tables, put them into source control, let the developers have access to those scripts and apply the scripts to the databse under change control?

Answer (score 1):

I've tackled this problem before by deferring contraints.

Normally, constraints are checked as data is inserted or updated in the row.  When a row is inserted, all the constraints are checked and the row either accepted or rejected.  You can, however, defer the constraint checking until the transaction commits. see:

http://www.remote-dba.cc/t_garmany_easysql_deferred_constraints.htm

This is vendor specific behaviour. It works in oracle but to the best of my knowledge is not supported in mysql.

Comment: The problem is not so much that the rows in the primary table will be temporarily deleted, but rather, once they're inserted again the value of the primary key will be different. If a DB allows PKs to be reused, they rows could be inserted with same PK value as before, but in my case I'm using MySQL auto-generated PKs

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source dbms systems, and dbunit looks reasonable.

I'm puzzled as to why you want to keep your master copy as a text file - why not use the database as a master?

Comment: I don't want to use the DB as a master because it's contents are not under source control, and developers don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate, you can use Castor to load an XML file of countries (for instance) into your Hibernate model objects, then persist those objects.

You may have to manage the insert/update/delete logic on your own...which can be summarized with this pseudocode:

- Load XML into Hibernate objects via Castor
- For each object:

  - If object is on the DB, invoke an update
  - If object is not on the DB, invoke save
- then for each record on the DB

  - Compare each record to your list of objects and delete if not found in your list

I hope that's clear...we have a similar process where a user will upload an XML file to refresh the DB.